# Changing Depth of Field focus speed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on my PC with ENBSeries' Depth of Field filter enabled, but the speed at which my focus changes is annoyingly slow. Is there a way to make it a bit faster? Is there a parameter in the file(s) which changes that?

Comment: Is this a mod, or have Bethesda added DoF to the game?

Comment: It is the ENBseries mod. It alters the way Direct3D renders the world, also adding DoF. By the way, I already got it fixed.

Comment: That's what I was guessing, but I know of at least one other DoF mod. You really do need to mention what mod you're talking about if you're going to ask a question about how to use the mod. ;)

Comment: @Ririshi How did you fix it? You can [answer your own question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) here.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my first question on here haha. Well the answer: open enbseries.ini in your Skyrim installation folder, search for [DEPTHOFFIELD] and in the entry FadeChange=x.x lower the number.

Comment: @Ririshi: If you could please post that as an answer and accept it, we could consider this question resolved, and you might gain some rep. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Open `enbseries.ini` in your Skyrim installation folder.

Search for `[DEPTHOFFIELD]` and in the entry`FadeTime=x.x`, lower the number.

Comment: Thank you SevenSidedDie, for doing the code formatting. I don't really understand it myself.